# if the first condition fails then the second condition will be examine -java

Tags: java, while-loop, conditional-statements

if i have a while condition in java as follows while(j>=1 && i<=7) my question is if the first condition fails then the second condition will be examine??
in other word if j=0 the compiler will check if I<=7 or it will ignore it .
please help me 
thank you

Comment: No, Execution will stop right there at the first one!!

Answer (score 6):

No, if the first condition returns **false** then the whole expression automatically returns **false**.

`Java` will not bother examining the other condition.

Answer (score 5):

```
(j>=1 && i<=7 && cond1 && cond2 && ... && condN) // will evaluate until the one condition fails
(j>=1  & i<=7  & cond1  & cond2  & ...  & condN) // will evaluate all the conditions
```

and with `or`

```
(j>=1 || i<=7 || cond1 || cond2 || ... || condN) // will evaluate until the one condition is true
(j>=1  | i<=7  | cond1  | cond2  | ...  | condN) // will evaluate all conditions
```

example:

lets use this 2 methods:

```
public boolean isTrue(){
  System.out.println("true");
  return true;
}

public boolean isFalse(){
  System.out.println("false");
  return false;
}
```

so, in the first case:

```
boolean cond = isFalse() && isTrue();
```

output is:

```
 false
```

value of cond is `false`

and in the second case:

```
boolean cond = isFalse() & isTrue();
```

output is:

```
 false
 true
```

value of cond is `false`

Answer (score 0):

It won't. Logical operator `&&` shortcuts and will stop evaluation if its left side argument is false.

Note that Java also has logical (in addition to the bitwise `&`!) operator `&`, which will *not* shortcut; therefore, if `a` is a boolean expression evaluating to false in `a & b`, then `b` *will* be evaluated nonetheless (but the end result will still be false).

Answer (score 0):

No while evaluating && if the first condition is false then it doesn't evaluate the second condition.

Similarly while evaluating || if the first condition is true then the second condition is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

This is called lazy evaluation. In order to make it greedy, use the single ampersand logical operator. In that case, it will also evaluate the second conditional, even if the first turns out to be false.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what others are saying.  The answer is no.  This is known as short-circuit evaluation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation